# Android, use a webview data for another webview?

Tags: android, web, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

Suppose I have a list view (I have json list).

On click, I'd like to show a detail view.
Right now, I'm requesting a new page from the server to show the detail view.

Thing is, detail view and the list view share the same html and javascript,(the url dictates whether it will be list-view or detail-view)
Furthermore, the list view already has the data in json format for the detail info.

It is perfectly easy if I show the detail view in the same activity (or fragment).
But I'm using a different activity for list and detail view.

Is there a way for me to show the detail view without requesting my server?
Since I have necessary html/javascripts/css/json data for the detail view at hand when I'm looking at the list view.

Comment: If you were able to access the html from the needed `WebView`, would it be helpful ?

Comment: from the html, I need to load css, and javascript and execute javascript. I don't need runtime context of javascript. (From html which I received from server as it is, and javascript files, css files, I can construct what I want)

Answer (score 0):

You can can create two separate div and show hide them.

Do not pass to next activity in this case, else u will have to reload all html js and css again, giving a white page for a couple of seconds.still u prefer to do then have a look at calling native funtion with js from webview and pass in arguments

However using a mobile based js like jquery mobile or angular would be proper way of developing such application.
Wherein all pages are loaded in one activity.